# The method (method) in the type (className) is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: java

I keep getting an error that I cannot seem to resolve. It appears on the "showSlide(elementNum);" line.

```
public class SlideGUI extends JPanel{


    fillSlide(); 
    showSlide();   

  }

    private class EventListener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getSource() == nextButton){
          elementNum++;

          if(elementNum == slides.length){
            elementNum = 0; //make index number 0 (the first slide)

        }
        }
     showSlide(elementNum);        
    }
  }


  public void fillSlide(){            

    slides[0] = new Slide("Halong Bay.jpg",new Color(49,57,74),"Halong Bay From     Lookout Point");
    slides[1] = new Slide("Minion.jpg",new Color(3,28,75),"Minion Balloon");
    slides[2] = new Slide("Ice Cream.jpg",new Color(13,54,72),"Chocolate Ice Cream with Yoghurt and Coffee Jelly");
  }

  public void showSlide(){

    imageLabel.setIcon(slides[elementNum].getImage());
    captionLabel.setText(slides[elementNum].getCaption());

    lowerPanel.setBackground(slides[elementNum].getColour());
    upperPanel.setBackground(slides[elementNum].getColour());
    moveOnPanel.setBackground(slides[elementNum].getColour());
    moveBackPanel.setBackground(slides[elementNum].getColour());
    picturePanel.setBackground(slides[elementNum].getColour());

  }
}
```

Comment: It means that `showSlide()`, a method declared to take no arguments, cannot be called with `showSlide(elementNum)`, which is attempting to supply an argument. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)

Comment: The error message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: @Raedwald I'm new to Java so I'm still trying to get my head around the basics, I'm mostly self taught

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `showSlide()` with a parameter, but you declared it to have no parameters.

Comment: I tried changing "slowSlide()" to "showSlide(0)" to start showing the first slide in the arraylist but it gave me another error

Comment: Instead of public void showSlide() you need to write public void showSlide(int elementNum)